# CMake target_include_directories does not affect header files

Tags: c++, cmake

My project is roughly structured like this:

```
├CMakeLists.txt
|
├───ExampleApp
|   ├───CMakeLists.txt
|   ├───header.hpp
|   └───main.cpp
|
└───ExampleLibrary
    ├───CMakeLists.txt
    ├───mylib.hpp
    └───mylib.cpp
```

In the root CMakeLists.txt I call

```
add_subdirectory(ExampleLibrary)
add_subdirectory(ExampleApp)
```

To build the library I call:

```
add_library(ExampleLibrary
    mylib.hpp mylib.cpp
)
```

And finally, in the executable, I try to do:

```
add_executable(ExampleApp
    header.hpp main.cpp
)

target_include_directories(ExampleApp
    PRIVATE ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/ExampleLibrary
)

target_link_libraries(ExampleApp
    Path/To/The/Binary/Directory
)
```

Now the build files generate just fine, and the project also builds with no errors. However, when I now try to include `mylib.hpp` in `header.hpp`, I get build errors because it can't find the file `mylib.hpp`. But I actually can include `mylib.hpp` in `main.cpp` and the project builds and compiles.

Am I missing something? I thought `target_include_directories()` works for both `.cpp` and `.hpp` files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you may not have added the correct directory as an *include directory* for the `ExampleApp`. The `PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR` variable evaluates to the directory in which the last `project()` call was made in your CMake project. You have not shown where this is, but you could use the **root** directory of the CMake project to be sure it is correct; try using `${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/ExampleLibrary` in the `target_include_directories` call instead:

```
target_include_directories(ExampleApp
    PRIVATE ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/ExampleLibrary
)
```

*A couple more notes:*

- If you aren't using an IDE such as Visual Studio for compilation, there is no need to add header files to calls like `add_library()` and `add_executable()`. Doing this only ensures they are shown in an IDE.
- Instead, specify *directories* within which the headers can be found, using `target_include_directories()`. In your case, it sounds like you should have *both* directories listed here.
- To link the `ExampleLibrary` target to the executable, you can simply use the target name in `target_link_libraries()`. There is no need to list out the binary directory (unless you are linking other libraries from there).

So with this in mind, the `ExampleApp` CMake file could look something like this:

```
add_executable(ExampleApp
    main.cpp
)

target_include_directories(ExampleApp PRIVATE 
    ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/ExampleLibrary
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}
)

target_link_libraries(ExampleApp PRIVATE
    ExampleLibrary
)
```

Comment: Thanks! Removing the headers from the add_executable() call fixed the issue